# What is the best way to evaluate False as -1 and True as 1?

Tags: python

I have a formula which I want `(Result for False) == -1*(Result for True)`. What quick (read: one-line) way can I express False as -1 and True as 1? Of course, if/else would work. I'm wondering about the most succinct way to express this.

Comment: What's wrong with `if-else`? You can use a conditional expression, sure, but surely you are better off wrapping this logic in a function and using that function. `def my_bool(x): return -1 if x is False else 1`. functions are the best way to write modular, succinct code

Comment: Nothing really, just wondered if there was a simple syntax convention escaping me. It appears there isn't. Thanks.

Comment: Well, you can do all sorts of compact ways of doing a terneray expression-like operation, e.g. `[-1, 1][x]` but why? Your code should be *readable*

Answer (score 7):

Use ternary expression:

```
result = 1 if bool else -1
```

Answer (score 3):

You could do:

```
a = False
b = True

print(2 * a - 1)
print(2 * b - 1)
```

**Output**

```
-1
1
```

Answer (score 2):

If the value is in `my_value` you can write `1 if my_value else -1`.

Answer (score 1):

Besides all the `if else` answers, here's an interesting (but more implicit) way:

```
result = -1 + 2*bool
```

This works because as @juanpa.arrivillaga notes in the comments section, `bool` is a subclass of `int` in Python and you can actually think of `True` and `False` as integers (1 and 0) defined everywhere. That is exactly how `True + True` yields `2`

Comment: `bool` is a subclass of int, i.e. `isinstance(True, int)` is true, so you can more thank think of them that way. that is how it is

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga thanks for the feedback, tried to add that in